# How can I send socket.io messages to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sockets, socket.io

I have a chat application similar to the one on socket.io's front page. I want to save the the messages with monogdb / mongoose so that they will always be there after refreshes / server restarts (just to learn how it would work).

So for example in my mongoose file I have this :

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var Mes = new Schema({
    content    : String
});

mongoose.model( 'Mes', Mes );
mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://localhost/socketio' );
```

And I want to save all my messages with that.

```
var db = require('./db.js');
...
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.emit('uconnected')
  socket.broadcast.emit('connected')
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    io.emit('disconnect')
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });});
```

So I don't know how to do this, I've had some ideas but non of them have worked.
I know you have to add this somewhere.

```
new Mes({
  content : $('#m').val(),
}).save( function ( err, todo, count ){
      if( err ) return next( err );
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var db = require('./db.js');
var Mes=require('Mes');
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('uconnected')
    socket.broadcast.emit('connected')
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        io.emit('disconnect')
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
        Mes.create({content:msg}, function (err,success) {
            if(err)
            {
                //handle error
            }
            else{
                //handle success
            }
        })
    });});
```

Comment: Ok I guess that works. In the `else{}` I put `console.log(success.content)` and it shows up with my message, however I want to save the messages, so I always see them... How would I accomplish that?

Comment: You can do anything in success callback. I would suggest you `emitting` message only on success callback, just to maintain all things in sync..Cheers !!!

Comment: I put the emit in the success. But It still deletes all messages after a refresh.

Comment: Debug your error callback, Just see if value is being added once message is received.

Comment: No errors. I'm pretty sure its being added. BTW im used to using `new Mes(..)` rather than `Mes.create` whats the difference?

Comment: When are you fetching the data back ? You need to pre-fill the data on `init` or `page-load`, it wont come there on its own..

Comment: Oh. That's what I'm doing wrong. Thanks! How should I go about pre-filling the data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90160/discussion-between-rayon-dabre-and-manu).